# How to change <foo>foovar></foo> to <span class = 'classname' >foovar</span> in php

Tags: php, html

What I want to do in php is to parse for example:-

`<foo>foovar></foo>` to `<span class='largerfont'>foovar</span>`

using something like:-

```
$customReplace = [
  "foo"=>"largerfont",
];
```

I know how to replace the string but only with different tags not with custom string like I use in the example using `preg_replace` but I don't know if I can archive this using `preg_replace` as well.

Comment: Something like this you want:- https://eval.in/728645?

Comment: @Anant yes but what if want to use another patterns thats why I wanted to use an array or something to store the patterns, what I mean is I want to foreach all the patterns to find the tags inside a string to replace them with their own span classes like <small>string</small>anothertext<medium>string2>medium>loremipsum
to <span ='smallclass'>string</span>anothertext<span='mediumclass'>string2</span>loremipsum

Comment: you can put n number of pattern and their corresponding replacement  and that's it.

Comment: @Anant True!! I was a little lost haha Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace()`:-

```
<?php

$parttern = array('/<foo>/','/<\/\foo>/');

$replace = array("<span class='largerfont'>",'</span>');

$string = '<foo>foovar></foo>';

echo $final_string = preg_replace($parttern,$replace,$string);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/728645

Answer (score 0):

You could use a couple of nested  replace

```
$string = str_replace('</foo>' , '</span>' ,
       str_replace("<foo>", "<span class='largerfont'>", "<foo>foovar></foo>"));
```